# How to modify a set of Markdown files using scripting

Tags: wordpress, shell

I have migrated my blog from Wordpress to Jekyll and I need to reset the `permalink` attribute of each file in my folder.
At the moment the file has this value:

```
permalink: /custom/url/.aspx
```

and I would like to reset to

```
permalink: /archive/:year/:month/:day/:title/categories/
```

Using a scripting like Power Shell or Node.js or Ruby. I can't do it with Regex because there is not a real configuration pattern I can follow. I am just aware of the fact that each .md file has **1 line** containing the pattern *permalink: [some value] `new line`*

Comment: Do I understand this right: you have a set of files, and in all these files, you want to replace the line starting with `permalink:` with the one from your second example?

Comment: Yes that's exactly what I need but with regex is not working

Comment: Do you have access to sed? You could do `sed -i 's|permalink: .*|permalink: /archive/:year/:month/:day/:title/categories/|' filename.md`.

Comment: Great, I'll try it. Because other script languages do not have good API for markdown.